# pergunta conceitual de front-end

Tags: javascript, html, css

Display: none piora a performance da página? Caso tenha vários elementos com esse display, seria melhor, por exemplo, ter uma classe para construi-los? Teoricamente poderíamos remover o elemento com o remove(), e ele seria deletado da página. Testando aqui, um elemento com display: 'none' é carregado quando se entra na página. Ele só não está no document flow

Comment: Depende: página dinâmica ou estática? Elemento oculto com muito conteúdo ou pouco? Caso a página seja estática, só o primeiro carregamento vai levar um pouco mais de tempo, depois ganha-se desempenho com o cache do navegador. O navegador em si praticamente não gasta tempo com elementos ocultos com display: 'none', o tempo é gasto no servidor para transferir os dados. Caso o ganho de desempenho não seja relevante, é mais simples exibir/ocultar um elemento que criá-lo dinamicamente com javascript ou fazer uma requisição ajax, que vai precisar até de desenvolvimento de código no backend.

Comment: Ah, entendi! Bem, no meu caso eu estou usando uma api para ter os dados (pokeApi), então acaba sendo mais fácil usar classe para exibi-los. Mas fiquei pensando nisso de desempenho enquanto fazia xD.

Comment: Sim, se não vai adicionar mão de obra de desenvolvimento no seu processo criar ao invés de ocultar/exibir, manda ver.